# Iterate over characters in string in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, optimization, substring, distance

First at all I have a very concrete question, but maybe an alternative approach to my problem (second part) could also help me.

**Is there a way to address a character in a string via its index in mysql. (i.e. in PHP $var[2] will give you the 3rd charater)?**

The obvious way is `SUBSTRING(var, 3,1 )` but since my strings are 1024 character long I assume this is not the fastest solution. As displayed in the code sample using substring to retrieve the tail of the string also gain no performance difference. Is there maybe a way to iterate over a string? (Shift the first element?)

```
CREATE FUNCTION hashDiff( hash1 TEXT(1024), hash2 TEXT(1024), threshold INT) 
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE diff, x, b1, b2 INT;
    SET diff =0;
    SET x = 0;
    WHILE (x<1024 AND diff<threshold)  DO
        SET b1 = ASCII(hash1); --uses first character only!!
        SET b2 = ASCII(hash2);
        SET hash1=SUBSTRING(hash1, 2 );
        SET hash2=SUBSTRING(hash2, 2 );
        SET diff=diff+ ((b1-b2)*(b1-b2));
        SET x=x+1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN diff;
END
```

If you not already read it from the code, I try to write a stored procedure to calculate the difference or distance between to hashes. The difference is the sum of the character-wise square distances (i.e. `hashDiff(AA,AC)=(65-65)²+(65-67)²=4`). The first major performance boost could be achieved by introducing a threshold to cancel the calculation if the hashes are already to different. But since mysql is not my "every day" language, I stuck at this point in finding other optimizations. For completeness two sample hashes:

> YAAAAAAYAAAYAAVAAQAARAOAAOAQASAQAMAKAKAJIAJAJIAHAHIAKJAIIAHHAHIIAIHGAGFFAGGFEAFEEEEAEDDDDDAEEEEDEEEFAFFFFFFEFFFEFFFFFGFEEFFEEEFFFJEFFEEEEEEELFFFFEEFJEEEEDIEEEEEIEEEEHEEEJEEFKFEFKGGFNHGOIIJTJKYONYNMTGHNHHQISJJQIKWLXJJSMYRQWJOGKDDFCCBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAAYAAAYAAWAARAASASAAQARAUAYAYATAOALKAJAJIAIAHHAHGAGFAFFAEFFAEFFAFFFAEEFFAFEEEDADEDDDDADDDCDDDDDAEEEFEEEEDDDEEEDEDDEEEFEFFGGFMFHGFFFGFFFLGHGGHGGNHHGGGOHGHGHMGGFGMFFFMFGFLFFFMGFFMGGMGGGNGGMGGLGGLGGMGGLEIEEHDCGCGCDGDGDCGDFCECCECECECECFCECFCFCFCFCFCGCJGYCYAAAAAAYAAAYAAUAATAAUAUAAUARARAQAPAPASARRAPARQAPAQQAQQAQSAKMATKKAIIHAIHGAGGGGAGHHGGAGGFGFFAFFGEFFFFFAFFGFGGGFFFEEFGFFGGFGGHIJJLKLWLKJJIJJJKJRLJKLKKKUKLLKKUMMKJIQIIIISKJJWKLLXMLMYMLNYMMYMLLWJIQIINFGKFFKEEIDHEDHDDFCECCFDECCFCFDGCDGCGCGEGCDCECECFDFCGDGCIEKEOAYNFBREUXKPQMMQTKTMMNJLPPVYYYTOUOPOLLJKKJJJIJIMJJJLIJJLLJIIHHIHHHIGHIHIHJHHHJHHIHGHGHFGHGFFEFEEEFEFEFFGGHIHIHGHGHHIIIIHIIJMNLONKLKKKKKKKMLKKLONMKOOOMLOPONMNMKKLLKKLMNKLMMMNMOPPOORPORSSVRTSSRTRRTSSTTXSTQRPONOKKLKLJMKJJIJIIHHHIIIJHIJIJJIJIKJIMWMYYDAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> AAAAAAAAAAABAABAACAACACAACADADAEADADADADDAEAEEAEAFEAEEAEFAFGAGGGAGGGAHHHAHIIIAIHIJHAIIHIHHAJIHIJIJKJAJJJIKJJJJKKJKJKKLKLKLLMMMNNMYOOOOOOPOONYOONONNPYNOOOPYOOPPPYNONNYMLLWLLKUJIISHIHOGGMFGFLFFMGGLFGLGFLFFKFKFFLEEKFLEFJFKFGNGNHLFHJFIEGDIEKGOIRFGBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABABACACDACADDACADDADDAEDAFEAEEFAFFFAFFGAFGGGAIGHHIAHIHHHHAHIHIIJJIIAIIIIJIJKJIIIIJJHIIHIIIIJIIIIRJJJJKJJJJLVKLLKLLKXLMMKMXMLLLMWMMMMYMNLYMNNYNNMYMMNYMLYLMLXKJRIHPHIMGGMFEJEJEEIEEHDGCDFCFDCFCECECCEBEBECFDGCFDNGLDBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAABAABABAACACACACACACACADDADAEEAFAFGAFGAHGAGGAGGHAGGIAIHJAJJJJAJKKKKAMLMNNNANOMMNNMMNAONMNOOOMOOPOMNOMMNPOOPPPPRQQYPPRPPPPPNOYLLMMMMLYLMLMLYLMLMMYLNNMYNLLWMLKXLLLUKIKQIIQGHHPFHNGFLFFLGFJEEJEIDDIDCHDFCDGCFCCFCECECCECFCGDGDHDHDIFIDEBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABBBBBCBCCCCDCCCCCCCCDDDDEDEEEEFFDEGGHGHHHGHHHHHHIIJJJJJIJJJJJJIKJJKLKKMMNMMMMMMMNNNNNNLNNONPONNNOOOOPQQQRSSSSSSUTSTUUUVWVVXUYXWVXVXWYVYWYVYYUWVUTTSSPQPQOPOPONONOMONOOONNNMMNLJJKJIIJHHGGGFHFGFFFFEEEDDEEEEFGGIGJLRNEAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: you might be able to handle your strings four bytes at a time with the HEX function.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you would be able to use an array of sorts would be to use a temporary tables and cursors/resultsets.

The problem is you will still need to iterate over the strings and use substring to break them apart.  To my knowledge there is no 'wordwrap' or 'explode' function to chop up the string.